# KeyError("word '%s' not in vocabulary" % word)

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, word2vec

After transforming my predicted labels from images into a list all_tags and later splitting them and finally storing into word_list which has all the labels stored in a sentence like structure.

All I want to do is use Google's Word2Vec pre-trained model (https://mccormickml.com/2016/04/12/googles-pretrained-word2vec-model-in-python/) to to generate and print all the Word2Vec values of my predicted labels. Imported and mapped the pretrained weight of the model, yet I'm getting the error

> KeyError: "word '['cliff'' not in vocabulary"

However, the word 'cliff' is available in the dictionary. Any insight will be well appreciated. 
Please check the code snippets below for reference.

```
execution_path = os.getcwd()
TEST_PATH = '/home/guest/Documents/Aikomi'


prediction = ImagePrediction()
prediction.setModelTypeAsDenseNet()
prediction.setModelPath(os.path.join(execution_path, "/home/guest/Documents/Test1/ImageAI-master/imageai/Prediction/Weights/DenseNet.h5"))
prediction.loadModel()

pred_array = np.empty((0,6), dtype=object)

predictions, probabilities = prediction.predictImage(os.path.join(execution_path, "1.jpg"), result_count=5)

for img in os.listdir(TEST_PATH):
    if img.endswith('.jpg'):
        image = Image.open(os.path.join(TEST_PATH, img))
        image = image.convert("RGB")
        image = np.array(image, dtype=np.uint8)
        predictions, probabilities = prediction.predictImage(os.path.join(TEST_PATH, img), result_count=5)
        temprow = np.zeros((1,pred_array.shape[1]),dtype=object)
        temprow[0,0] = img
        for i in range(len(predictions)):
            temprow[0,i+1] = predictions[i]
        pred_array = np.append(pred_array, temprow, axis=0)


all_tags = list(pred_array[:,1:].reshape(1,-1))
_in_sent = ' '.join(list(map(str, all_tags)))


import gensim
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
import re
import random
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')


word_list = _in_sent.split() 

from gensim.corpora.dictionary import Dictionary

# be sure to split sentence before feed into Dictionary
word_list_2 = [d.split() for d in word_list]
dictionary = Dictionary(word_list_2)
print("\n", dictionary, "\n")

corpus_bow = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in word_list_2]

model = Word2Vec(word_list_2, min_count= 1)
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('/home/guest/Downloads/Google.bin', binary=True)

print(*map(model.most_similar, word_list))
```

Comment: As @imtinan-azhar notes in their answer, your error is actually reporting that the word `"['cliff'"` is not in the word-vectors, which is not surprising (even if the word `"cliff"` is present). Also, you should show the full error-stack of any errors you want solved – so the exact lines involved are highlighted. Finally, the line `model = Word2Vec(word_list_2, min_count= 1)` has no contribution to your end result, because on the very next line you assign something different – a loaded set of Google's vectors – into the `model` variable, discarding whatever `Word2Vec` model you'd just created.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is right there, you very clearly printed

```
KeyError(“word '%s' not in vocabulary” % word)
```

and the error is

> KeyError: "word '['cliff'' not in vocabulary"

Since the contents of the variable word should be between ' and '
Hence the word variable has the string `['cliff'` not the string `cliff`

Remove punctuation from your text, like ' and [ ] etc.

Comment: But the word is very much there if i print all_tags.

Comment: I get that, but the word used to query the dictionary is not `cliff` , it has a [ and ' in it,   it is `['cliff'`, thats why its failing, clean the word variable to have only letters and it will work

Comment: Try this , add this line to your code before quering the dictionary `regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]')`
`word_list = [regex.sub('',w) for w in word_list]`

Comment: It's showing Dictionary(522 unique tokens: ['cliff', 'valley', 'lakeside', 'seashore', 'promontory']...)
After adding your snippet, the result is the same.
regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]') 
word_list = [regex.sub('',w) for w in word_list]

word_list = _in_sent.split() 
from gensim.corpora.dictionary import Dictionary

Comment: could you print the variable words_list and show that here?

Comment: KeyError: "word 'custardapple' not in vocabulary"

Comment: ['cliff',
 'valley',
 'lakeside',
 'seashore',
 'promontory',
 'custard_apple',
 'cauliflower',
 'broccoli',
 'fig',
 'head_cabbage',
 'Great_Dane',
 'book_jacket',.....